# Is there a way to put 3D user-rotatable AutoCAD drawings on my website?

Tags: images, 3d

Is there not a very problematic and a cheap way to convert my AutoCAD 3D technical drawings to browser acceptable format, probably, flash? I'd like to put 3D drawing to a site in a way visitors could rotate them with mouse drag-and-drops clicks, well, like Google 3D panoramic street view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export/save in Autocad to the X3d format, upload that to your site, and use a [VRML](http://cic.nist.gov/vrml/vbdetect.html) plugin for any of those listed players to view the file.  Which means providing a link on the page for others to download the plugin so they can do the same thing.

Comment: looks like a quite suitable solution, I'll try it, thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, plug-in is a not a think one can install on a public computer...

Comment: Then, you are indeed looking at a customized solution like a flash construct, if you need "universally" accessibility.  There are multiple plugins and 3d viewers available, but none are included by default with any of the browsers one can expect on a public terminal... due to how rare these things are.

Comment: Maybe you can use [three.js](http://threejs.org/): export to a format that [can be converted to json](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/580#issuecomment-2193038). If you want it simpler take a example and just change the model.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which uses a Java applet. It's universal if you consider Java Runtime is on most computers. No plug-in installation required, just needs a browser. Works on Mac and Windows.
Learn more here: http://altadyn.com/developers-api/

Comment: Except it does’t work on any iPhone, iPad and on Mac OS Lion is optional.